# Fastest way to filter lists of lists based on a third list?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a list `A` like the following:

```
A = np.array([[1,2] ,
              [2,4] ,
              [3,4] , 
              [4,5] , 
              [6,7]])
```

and I need to remove all sublists containing any of the elements in a third list `B`.

So if for example:

```
B = [1,2,5]
```

The expected result would be:

```
np.array([[3,4] ,
          [6,7]])
```

The length of A gets up to 1,500,000 and B is also often in the tens of thousands of elements, so performance is critical. The length of the sublists of `A` is always 2.

Comment: how big are the sublists of `a`? for example what is `len(a[123])`? Is it bigger or smaller than `b`?

Comment: Also is `b = [1, 2, 5]` in this example?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was not clear. Editting now. 

the sublists of a are always 2 values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All approaches presented here are based on [numpys boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). The approach is to identify matches (independant of row) and then use a reduction ([`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) or [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all)) along the rows to see which rows should be eliminated and which should be kept. Finally this mask is applied to your array `A` to get only the valid rows. The only real difference between the approaches is how you create the mask.

#### Approach 1:

If the values of `B` are known in advance you generally use `|` (or operator) chained comparisons.

```
a[~np.any(((a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 5)), axis=1)]
```

I'll go through this step-by-step:

1. Finding matches

   ```
   >>> ((a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 5))
   array([[ True,  True],
          [ True, False],
          [False, False],
          [False,  True],
          [False, False]], dtype=bool)
   ```
2. Check each row for one `True`:

   ```
   >>> np.any(((a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 5)), axis=1)
   array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
   ```
3. Invert it:

   ```
   >>> ~np.any(((a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 5)), axis=1)
   array([False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
   ```
4. Use boolean indexing:

   ```
   >>> a[~np.any(((a == 1) | (a == 2) | (a == 5)), axis=1)]
   array([[3, 4],
          [6, 7]])
   ```

#### Approach 2:

Instead of these `a == 1 | a == 2 | ...` you could also use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.in1d(a, [1, 2, 5]).reshape(a.shape)
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and then use essentially the same approach as above

```
>>> a[~np.any(np.in1d(a, [1, 2, 5]).reshape(a.shape), axis=1)]
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

#### Approach 3:

In case `b` is sorted you can also use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to create the mask:

```
>>> np.searchsorted([1, 2, 5], a, side='left') == np.searchsorted([1, 2, 5], a, side='right')
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This time you'd need to check if `all` values in reach row are `True`:

```
>>> b = [1, 2, 5]
>>> a[np.all(np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left') == np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right'), axis=1)]
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

#### Timings:

The first approach isn't exactly suitable for arbitary `B` so I don't include it in these timings.

```
import numpy as np

def setapproach(A, B):  # author: Max Chrétien
    B = set(B)
    indices_to_del = [i for i, sublist in enumerate(A) if B & set(sublist)]
    C = np.delete(A, indices_to_del, 0)
    return C

def setapproach2(A, B):  # author: Max Chrétien & Ev. Kounis
    B = set(B)
    return np.array([sublist for sublist in A if not B & set(sublist)])

def isinapproach(a, b):
    return a[~np.any(np.in1d(a, b).reshape(a.shape), axis=1)]

def searchsortedapproach(a, b):
    b.sort()
    return a[np.all(np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left') == np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right'), axis=1)]

A = np.random.randint(0, 10000, (100000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 2000)

%timeit setapproach(A, B)
# 929 ms ± 16.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit setapproach2(A, B)
# 1.04 s ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit isinapproach(A, B)
# 59.1 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit searchsortedapproach(A, B)
# 56.1 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The timings, however depend on the range of values, if `B` is already sorted and the lengths of `A`, `B`. But the numpy approaches seams to be almost 20 times faster than the set-solutions. However the difference is mostly because iteration over numpy-arrays with python loops is really inefficient so I'll convert `A` and `B` to `list`s first:

```
def setapproach_updated(A, B):
    B = set(B)
    indices_to_del = [i for i, sublist in enumerate(A.tolist()) if B & set(sublist)]
    C = np.delete(A, indices_to_del, 0)
    return C

def setapproach2_updated(A, B):
    B = set(B)
    return np.array([sublist for sublist in A.tolist() if not B & set(sublist)])
```

That may seem strange but let's redo the timings:

```
%timeit setapproach_updated(A, B)
# 300 ms ± 2.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit setapproach2_updated(A, B)
# 378 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This is much faster than the plain loops, just by converting it with `tolist` first, but still 5+ times slower than the numpy approaches.

So remember: **When you have to use *Python-based approaches* on NumPy arrays check if it is faster to convert it to a list first!**

Let's see how that performs on bigger arrays (these are sizes that approximate those mentioned in your question):

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, (1500000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, 50000)

%timeit setapproach_updated(A, B)
# 4.14 s ± 66.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit setapproach2_updated(A, B)
# 6.33 s ± 95.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit isinapproach(A, B)
# 2.39 s ± 102 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit searchsortedapproach(A, B)
# 1.34 s ± 21.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The differences got smaller and the `searchsorted`-approach definetly wins.

#### Approach 4:

I'm not finished yet! Let me surprise you with [numba](/questions/tagged/numba), it's not a lightweight package **but** extremly powerful **if** it supports the types and functions you need:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit                # the magic is this decorator
def numba_approach(A, B):
    Bset = set(B)
    mask = np.ones(A.shape[0], dtype=nb.bool_)
    for idx in range(A.shape[0]):
        for item in A[idx]:
            if item in Bset:
                mask[idx] = False
                break
    return A[mask]
```

Let's see how that performs:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10000, (100000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 2000)

numba_approach(A, B)   # numba needs a warmup run because it's just-in-time compiling

%timeit numba_approach(A, B)
# 6.12 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# This is 10 times faster than the fastest other approach!

A = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, (1500000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, 50000)

%timeit numba_approach(A, B)
# 286 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# This is still 4 times faster than the fastest other approach!
```

So, you can make it another order of magnitude faster. Numba doesn't support all python/numpy features (and not all of them are faster) but in this case it's enough!

Comment: I have the feeling that the `[1, 2, 5]` is `b` which is *tens of thousands of elements big* so ...

Comment: I added an `in1d` and `searchsorted` approach which could scale better for long `b`s.

Comment: @KMoore agreed! thx guys, It's nice to have such detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) -
 intersection to recreate a new list of indices where `[1, 2, 5]` is in your sublists.
Then with the list of the indices to remove, use [`np.delete()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html#numpy.delete) function of integrated in numpy.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2],
              [2,4],
              [3,4],
              [4,5],
              [6,7]])

B = set([1, 2, 5])

indices_to_del = [i for i, sublist in enumerate(A) if B & set(sublist)]

C = np.delete(A, indices_to_del, 0)

print C
#[[3 4]
# [6 7]]
```

*EDIT*

Thanks to @MSeifert I was able to improve my answer.

@Ev.Kounis proposed another similar, but faster solution:

```
D = np.array([sublist for sublist in A if not B & set(sublist)])
```

Comment: If you do `set(B)` only once (before you do the comprehension) your approach won't scale too bad.

Comment: and instead of storing the indices and then deleting them you can just do `C = np.array([sublist for sublist in A if not B & set(sublist)])` using the exact same logic with a negation added (if the intersection of `sublist` and `B` is an empty set, store `sublist` to the `np.array`).

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You don't need the enumerate then :) Maybe that's better suited as additional answer though.

Comment: @MSeifert True, updated. Would you be perhaps willing to `time` the two answers?

Comment: Thx for the help guys. @Ev.Kounis I can delete my last solution if you want to post it as your own if you wish! I will enjoy a benchmark as well!

Comment: @MaxChrétien It's no problem mate. I might `time` them myself if I find the time xD

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I did the timings and appended them to my answer. :)

Comment: @MSeifert `numpy` never ceases to impress. Woww